API Accessing using Domain Wide Delegation
I'm trying to use Google Workspace's Directory API to list users and running into problems with permissions.  I get a 403 response with a message: "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
I'm using a Service Account authenticated via OAuth JWT with domain wide delegation.  On the Domain Wide Delegation page at: https://admin.google.com/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation  I see the Client ID for the account I'm using with the scopes:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member

First I hit: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token to get a token, which appears to happen successfully.  Then I hit the endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=******.org
For headers I have:
Authorization: Bearer [token]
Host: www.googleapis.com

The body is empty.
Does anyone have suggestions for how to troubleshoot this further?

You should have set up the permission beforehand, as shown in https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en#zippy=%2Cset-up-domain-wide-delegation-for-a-client. Is that done?

Yes, the Client ID and the scopes I listed above are on the Domain-wide Delegation screen as noted in that link.
